# Windows 10 Touchpad and Keyboard Not Working in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

I am very new to Linux, and recently installed Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows on my Windows 10 Surface laptop. However, while installing and logging into Ubuntu, I realized that the inbuilt keyboard and the touch pad were not working. Sound is also not working, but I'm unsure if that is related in any way. The keyboard works in BIOS, but instantly shuts off/disconnects when I boot Ubuntu, and both the mouse and keyboard work perfectly fine in Windows. Entering `xinput` with only a Logitech mouse plugged in gives
[this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DARs.png)
which seems to be saying that neither the keyboard nor the touchpad seem to be recognized by Ubuntu.
I've tried using a few of the other recommended solutions for similar problems on this site so far, with no success, e.g. reinstalling input-synaptics. Is there a way to get Ubuntu to at least recognize the keyboard and touch pad?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What is the exact model hardware?  Have you searched the manufacturer's support website to determine if there are any drivers available?

Comment: @Nmath I'm using the LTS 20.04 version, on a Surface 3 Laptop. In the windows hardware, the keyboard is just called a HID Keyboard Device and the touch pad is a "HID compliant mouse." I took a look at the available drivers for it, but they seem to only be windows drivers.